# Displaying pre-calculated estimates and error bars

Tags: powerbi

I would like to be able to display pre-calculated estimates and error bars.

For example:

[image]

[this is a design, not an example of a powerBI page]

My data would look like this:

```
variable     level            estimate     lower     upper
Remoteness   Major cities       280         258       301
Remoteness   Inner regional     260         243       292
Remoteness   Outer regional     260         247       287 
etcetera
```

Is there (1) a specific visual that can do this? Or (2) a workaround, for example, a visual that can display both a line (lower to upper) and a dot (estimate)?

Comment: In what language/software do you want to solve this issue?

Comment: This is PowerBI. Sorry, I had 'PowerBI' in the title AND in the description, but some editor adjusted my query and 'cleaned up' my question.

Answer (score 1):

you can achieve a similar output by using a Gantt chart with milestones. There are a couple of custom gantt chart visuals that you can use:

- Simplest: [Micrsoft Gantt](https://appsource.microsoft.com/en-us/product/power-bi-visuals/wa104380765?tab=overview) - simple and would provide an output that's close to what you're expecting. Its not exact output.
- feature rich: [xVix Gantt](https://xviz.com/blogs/efficient-project-management-power-bi-latest-gantt-chart/#:%7E:text=Milestone%20Moved%20to%20Advance%20Editor) - but there's a bit of a learning curve to get this to work as expected.

  - Demo: [xViz Gantt Demo](https://app.powerbi.com/view?r=eyJrIjoiNzM0MDI3MDYtZmIzMS00NDM4LWJkMDQtZjEzMzUyNjI0ODU0IiwidCI6IjlmODRlZTRiLWJlZTMtNDJmNy1iODRjLWU1N2U1ZTkyZjEwNSJ9&embedImagePlaceholder=true&pageName=ReportSection8d42e40996556e9b1309) - go to **Milestones**
    [image: xViz Demo Screenshot]

Comment: It's not the same...

Comment: Okay, can you clarify your question and point out the differences in the screenshot I attached vs your screenshot?